# Linux with AMD Ryzen 5 3600

Tags: linux, amd

Does Linux distributions Work with a Ryzen 5 3600 processor?

I am most interested in Debian, but other distributions too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

There  seem to be some issues with ACPI; many use `acpi=off`.

`pci=assign-busses apicmaintimer idle=poll reboot=cold,hard` seems a better solution.

A more elaborate explanation can be found at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234299/amd-ryzen-5-3600-ubuntu-20-04-problems

Answer (score 1):

I have an:
Notebook: Acer Nitro AN515-43
APU: AMD Ryzen 5 3550H with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx
RAM: 16GB (2x8GB) SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3200 MHz (0.3 ns)
Graphic 1: AMD Radeon Vega 8, Picasso
Graphic 2: Radeon RX 460/560D / Pro 450/455/460/555/555X/560/560X
NVME: 128GB M.2 SSD, Intel Pro 7600p/760p/E 6100p Series
HDD: 1TB S-ATA 5300RPM, HGST HTS721010A9
W-LAN: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
LAN: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
AMD-Chipset/Controller/IOMMU
OS: Kubuntu 20.04 GNU/Linux


Works very good, have no problems, very fast.
WiFi card dues not support Aircrack-ng
The Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (APIC) dues have a bug, hibernation is not work properly, cannot wake up from hibernation.
BIOS update can fix the issue but no BIOS update for have.



**dmesg | grep Error**

```
[    0.371660] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GPP0.SWUS], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/dswload2-162)
[    0.371666] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20200528/psobject-220)
[    0.371670] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GPP0.SWUS.SWDS], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/dswload2-162)
[    0.371674] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20200528/psobject-220)
[    0.544994] integrity: Error adding keys to platform keyring UEFI:db
[    0.545013] integrity: Error adding keys to platform keyring UEFI:db
[    0.709142] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Attempt to CreateField of length zero (20200528/dsopcode-133)
[    0.709171] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.GP17.VGA.ATRM due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20200528/psparse-52
```